# Sphinx search with int primary key

Tags: sphinx

I'm trying add int primary key as a sql_field_string, when I'm rotate index I get message:
WARNING: attribute 'purchase_id' not found - IGNORING

my config:

```
sp_purchases_source : sp_source_config
{

        sql_query = \
                SELECT sp_purchase.id AS purchase_id, sp_purchase.status, sp_purchase.name, sp_purchase.description_small, sp_purchase.description_full, sp_purchase.news,\
                UNIX_TIMESTAMP(sp_purchase.date_current) AS date_current, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(sp_purchase.stop_date) AS stop_date, sp_purchase.image, sp_purchase.access, \
                sp_purchase.is_vip, sp_purchase.is_foreign, sp_purchase.owner_username, sp_purchase.owner_id, sp_purchase.count_users, sp_purchase.count_comments \
                FROM sp_purchase \
                WHERE sp_purchase.is_hidden = 0 AND sp_purchase.status IN (2,4,17)

        sql_ranged_throttle = 0
        sql_field_string    = purchase_id
        sql_field_string    = name
        sql_field_string    = description_small
        sql_field_string    = description_full
        sql_field_string    = owner_username
        sql_field_string    = news
        sql_attr_timestamp  = date_current
        sql_attr_timestamp  = stop_date
        sql_attr_string     = image
        sql_attr_uint       = access
        sql_attr_uint       = owner_id
        sql_attr_uint       = status
        sql_attr_bool       = is_vip
        sql_attr_bool       = is_foreign
        sql_attr_uint       = count_users
        sql_attr_uint       = count_comments
}
```

how I can add id field in index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the document-id is **already** a virtual attribute. It works just like a real attribute.

So can filter/sort/group by id.

```
sphinxql> SELECT id,name FROM sp_purchases WHERE id BETWEEN 10 and 20;
```

... to make it a field, have to be a bit more tricky, eg duplicate it twice.

```
    sql_query = \
            SELECT sp_purchase.id, sp_purchase.id AS purchase_id, sp_purchase.status, ...
```

The first column is **always** the document-id, so will be used for virtual attribute.

So leaves `purchase_id` to be a 'standard' field.